# How to persist a saga in Rebus using MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, rebus

I'm configuring a bus, and I need to configure the way Rebus persists sagas. I would persist sagas in MongoDB using Official C# Mongo Driver version 1.10, so I'm writing something like:

```
return Rebus.Config.Configure.With(new CastleWindsorContainerAdapter(container))
    .Sagas(s => s.StoreInMongoDb())
    ...
```

where `StoreInMongoDB` is an extension method:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Configures Rebus to use MongoDB to store sagas, using the specified collection
//     name resolver function. If the collection name resolver is omitted, collection
//     names will be determined by using the Name property of the saga data's System.Type
public static void StoreInMongoDb(this StandardConfigurer<Rebus.Sagas.ISagaStorage> configurer, MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase, Func<Type, string> collectionNameResolver = null);
```

The question is: Since `MongoDatabase` does not implement `IMongoDatabase` how can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebus has been updated to use v. 2 of the official MongoDB driver.

It was done in order to take advantage of its ability to do proper C# `async`/`await`-supported asynchronous I/O.

I am afraid that there is currently no support for the old MongoDB driver (1.10 and earlier), although you might be able to dig it out of the Rebus history of you really need it.

I would suggest that you see if you can use the new driver, though, possibly writing a couple of your own extension methods in various places in order to supplement the rather crude API provided by the new version.

Comment: Yes I tried this way but it looks that Rebus.MongoDb (0.99 i.e. the latest stable) is compatible with mongocsharpdriver (>= 1.10.0 && < 2.0.0).

Comment: bummer!! sorry! :-S I accepted a PR at some point which upgraded the Rebus.MongoDb to use the driver version 2, but the .nuspec was not edited accordingly! That has been fixed now and will be out in 0.99.29 in a few minutes.... thanks for bringing this to my attention! :)

Comment: Perfect, if only would support legacy mongocsharpdriver would be perfect but don't worry. I clearly understand :D